# Vite: Identifier 'require$$0' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, vite, commonjs, rollup

I am trying to set up Vite build system for my existing project.

Dev build works fine, but when built for production, the bundle gives this error during runtime:

```
index.89943202.js:319 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index.89943202.js:319:23570
    at ir (index.89943202.js:305:34977)
    at index.89943202.js:319:23158
```

I've googled for solutions and added this option to my vite.config.cjs:

```
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true
    },
```

After that, the build now fails with:

```
file: proj-path/node_modules/some-custom-library/build/index.es.js:55:0
53: import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIos';
54: import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos';
55: import require$$0 from 'object-is';
    ^
56: import require$$1 from 'has';
57: import _propTypes from 'prop-types';
error during build:
Error: Identifier 'require$$0' has already been declared
```

This library is included through "module": "./build/index.es.js".

I think the problem here is that the library is somehow built in a separate context from the main bundle and now symbols overlap, because they didn't know about existing symbols during build time.

How to get rid of this error?

This is my Vite configuration:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from 'path';
import envCompatible from 'vite-plugin-env-compatible';
import { injectHtml } from 'vite-plugin-html';
import { viteCommonjs } from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker';

const dirname = __dirname


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: '@',
        replacement: path.resolve(dirname, 'src')
      }
    ],
    extensions: [
      '.mjs',
      '.js',
      '.ts',
      '.jsx',
      '.tsx',
      '.json',
      '.vue'
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    svgr(),
    react(),
    viteCommonjs(),
    envCompatible({ prefix: "REACT_APP" }),
    injectHtml(),
    checker({
      typescript: true,
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {},
    outDir: './build',
    minify: "esbuild",
    target: 'es2015',
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true
    },
  },
})
```